# SQL Query Problem Involving (SUM, Group By, Order by, I guess? and maybe total, or even count)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

By using SQL query, find out the Top 5 highest total Transaction Value, which Industry are they? and the number of stores in that industry?

My SQL data looks like this:

| Store Name | Industry | Transaction Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Ace | A | 196 |
| Ace | A | 193 |
| Area | A | 168 |
| Apple | A | 165 |
| Boy | B | 145 |
| Boy | B | 143 |
| Bull | B | 136 |
| Bread | B | 131 |
| Cat | C | 116 |
| Cat | C | 106 |
| Cake | C | 104 |
| Candy | C | 102 |
| Dog | D | 101 |
| Dog | D | 92 |
| Door | D | 80 |
| Daddy | D | 75 |
| Egg | E | 70 |
| Egg | E | 67 |
| Earl | E | 66 |
| Eagle | E | 61 |

This is just for your reference, Top 5 highest Transaction Value are:

| No. | Store Name | Industry | Total Transaction Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ace | A | 389 |
| 2 | Boy | B | 288 |
| 3 | Cat | C | 222 |
| 4 | Dog | D | 193 |
| 5 | Area | A | 168 |

SQL Query Results should look something like this:

| Industry | No. of Stores |
| --- | --- |
| A | 2 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 1 |
| E | 0 |

Comment: Which database you are using ?

Comment: @Linker Im using Snowflake SQL database

Comment: The task only becomes clear with the result data shown. "total transaction value" means per store name and industry. And per store name and industry translates to `GROUP BY store_name, industry` of course. But the top 5 highest? That's another problem with this kind of task. What if there are ties, e.g. #5 = 168 and #6 = 168. Shall we show all six rows then? Or only four? Or pick one of the two tying rows and thus show only five rows with the last one arbitrarily picked?

Comment: And then there are 5 industries in the result. Is this just all industries that happen to be present in the table? Or is there an industry table containing all industires we should use as a reference?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner 1)Just now a guy posted the first answer but he deleted it, not sure why. I immediately tried it out and it works, but without showing the E industry has 0 stores. 2) I guess the case where there are ties is unlikely, since the actual data I am working on are like, at least $12,345,678.90 for the top 5. If the case did happen, I wanted to include the ties, which results in showing 6 rows. If you happen to know how to do that, please let me know.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner In the actual data, it could be top 5, 10 or 20, and the industries shown could be A,C,E,G,H,J,Z and more, then by going into top 5, I wanted to put more focus on those industries that get into top 5, instead of showing all other industries that has 0 stores. For example, the results are A,2; B,1; C,1; D,1; E,0; F,0; G,0; and so on. My focus will be only on A, B, C and D, I don't really look into others, but of course it may be helpful if I create an industry table as reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select a.industry, sum(case when b.name is null then 0 else 1 end) as no 
from
    (select distinct industry from transactions ) a
left join
    (select name, industry 
    from transactions 
    group by name, industry
    order by sum(transaction_vaule) desc limit 5) b
on a.industry = b.industry
group by a.industry
order by a.industry
```

Comment: Good answer. But some explaining text would make it even better :-) `sum(case when b.name is null then 0 else 1 end)` is usually simply written as `count(b.name)` by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution for you. Please check my code I have used Common Table Expression ,`CASE`,`SUM` and `group by` =>

```
WITH CTE AS
(
SELECT industry, SUM(TransactionValue) AS Transaction_Value, 
COUNT(StoreName) AS StoreCount  FROM MYTable
    GROUP BY StoreName,industry
    ORDER BY SUM(TransactionValue) DESC
    Limit 5
)
SELECT T1.industry,
       SUM((CASE WHEN c.industry IS NULL THEN 0
       ELSE 1 END)) as CT
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Industry FROM MYTable) AS T1
LEFT JOIN CTE as c ON T1.industry=c.industry
GROUP BY  T1.industry
```

**Note:** Subquery is not best practice, but in your case, I think there will be no performance issue. Also, please check the code because, I do not have Snowflake SQL database installed, so there might be some syntactical error can be evident
.

Answer (score 0):

To get a deterministic result, you must be aware of ties. Let's say the top 9 results are

```
Cat/A/600, Dog/A/500, Cat/B/500, Dog/B/400, Cat/C/300, Dog/C/300, Cat/D/300, Dog/D/200, Cat/E/100
```

Which is the top fifth? Cat/C/300 or Dog/C/300 or Cat/D/300? Or none of them? If we pick a row arbitrarily (by `LIMIT 5` or `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS ONLY`) we prefer one industry over another.

In standard SQL we have the clause `FETCH FIRST 5 ROWS WITH TIES`, but snowflake doesn't feature this, unfortunately. It does however feature `DENSE_RANK`. It ranks my sample rows thus:

```
#1: Cat/A/600
#2: Dog/A/500
#2: Cat/B/500
#3: Dog/B/400
#4: Cat/C/300
#4: Dog/C/300
#4: Cat/D/300
#5: Dog/D/200
#6: Cat/E/100
```

because the five top values are 600, 500, 400, 300, and 200.

The query:

```
select industry, count(case when rnk <= 5 then 1 end) as stores
from
(
  select industry, dense_rank() over (order by sum(transaction_value) desc) as rnk
  from mytable
  group by store_name, industry
) ranked
group by industry
order by industry;
```

If you only want to show top industries:

```
select industry, count(*) as stores
from
(
  select industry, dense_rank() over (order by sum(transaction_value) desc) as rnk
  from mytable
  group by store_name, industry
) ranked
where rnk <= 5
group by industry
order by industry;
```

Comment: SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 0 unexpected '('.

Comment: Oh. 'FROM' is missing before the bracket '(', your solution solves my problem too. Thanks

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot the `FROM` keyword. Sorry about that. Thanks for finding the error. I am glad our queries work for you. And I hope you learn a thing or two from them :-)